# What are objects in the substructure referring to?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

> Firstly, a cardinal κ is inaccessible if and only if κ has
>   the following reflection property: for all subsets U ⊂
>   V<sub>κ</sub>, there exists α < κ such that
>   $(V_\alpha,\in,U\cap V_\alpha)$ is an elementary substructure of
>   $(V_\kappa,\in,U)$.

But usually for a structure, $(A,\sigma,I)$ $A$ would refer to domain, $\sigma$ would be signature and $I$ would be interpretation - so in this case, what are three objects in $( \, \, \,   )$ in the quote are referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For models of (fragments of) set theory, in the structure $( V , \in , A )$ the set $A$ is taken to be a new unary relation such that $A(x)$ holds iff $x \in A$.  (So these are technically structures over a different language which has in addition to the binary $\in$ an extra unary relation symbol).